# throuhput keep descreasing in Jmeter benchmark

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

When I'm doing Jmeter benchmark, the throughput and transfer bytes/sec keep decreasing as time goes by? Who can tell me why? 
When the test begins, it has a high throughput , but it decreases all time, and the stable status can't be accessed.

Comment: how many users you are using for load test? what is rampup and test duration? Because initially when users are ramping up system is not stable thus lot of fluctuation are obvious but after some time as system gets stable you should get stable throughput after a steady point.

Comment: the number of users is 20 and rampup is 1. I observed for more than 5 minutes, but it did not get stable and it's throughput was just 1/3 of the original.

Comment: you are hitting application with 20 users in 1 second which is not so critical but it is high(depends on application). try to do it with 5-10 seconds rampup. About stability it again depends on system. some systems may get stable in 1 min and some may take 10-15 min. Let the test for long duration  (30 min etc.). If after that also its not getting stable then something is wrong with application. Try to tune it.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter kicks off threads representing virtual users according to your ramp-up. Each thread starts executing samplers upside down (or according to parent Logic Controllers). When thread doesn't have more samplers to execute and no more loops to iterate it's being shut down.

You can consider the following approaches to implement desired load scenario:

1. Provide enough iterations via Thread Group or [Loop Contoller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)
2. Use [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which provides easy way of defining a load scenario so you will be able to set initial users number, ramp up duration and users arrival rate, time to hold the load, and define ramp-down.

   [image: Ultimate Thread Group]
3. JMeter provides [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) which can be used to set precise load in "requests per minute" so you'll be able to control target throughput. You can also use it in conjunction with [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) - this way you can dynamically change throughput on-the-fly.